# Export json in javascript function to be imported in another javascrtipt function

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-blade, javascript-import

I have a requirement to read a json file and make it available across the application. My approach was (extracted from this [resource](https://ideas.hexbridge.com/how-to-use-laravel-routes-in-javascript-4d9c484a0d97)):

**assets/js/routes.json**:

```
{
    "task.create": "deliveryorders\/{deliveryOrder}\/tasks\/create",
}
```

**assets/js/router.js**:

```
import * as routes from './routes.json';

export function route() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var name = args.shift();

    if (routes[name] === undefined) {
        console.error('Unknown route ', name);
    } else {
        return baseUrl + '/' + routes[name]
            .split('/')
            .map(s => s[0] == '{' ? args.shift() : s)
            .join('/');
    }
}
```

**assets/js/base/pltbl.js**:

```
import '../router.js';

window.tblLoadContent = function tblLoadContent(argModel) {
    url_ = route(argModel.name + ".index", [argModel.parent_id]);
    $("#tbl" + _titleCase(argModel.name) + "_body").load(url_, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success") {
            refreshMenu(argModel);
        }
    });
}
```

It is called in **app.blade.php**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tblLoadContent("{'name':'package', 'parent_id': '1'}");
});
```

But when the app.blade.php is rendered, pops below error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined
  at tblLoadContent (pltbl.js:141)
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (edit:473)
  at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
  at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need or to create a default export or to import the route  with curly braces.
Option 1:

```
export default function route()
```

Option 2:

```
import {route} from '../router.js';
```

Comment: in pltbl.js: `import {route} from '../router.js';` and in router.js: `import * as routes from './routes.json';` Thanks (Y)